# Codeigniter admin controller in subfolder issue while pagination

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter.i have create subfolder for admin controller like

Controller->admin->news.php

Now when i am access the news controller its working fine like

http://mysite.com/sacha/admin`enter code here`/news

But when i am trying edit delete or pagination like

http://mysite.com/sacha/admin/news/index/1

or

.../sacha/admin/news/1

Its showing 404 page not found error

Routes which i am using is

```
    $route['admin/news'] = 'admin/news';
    $route['admin/news/index'] = 'admin/news/index';
    $route['admin/news/(:num)'] = 'admin/news/$1';
    $route['admin/news/index/(:num)'] = 'admin/news/index/$1';
```

I used (:any) also but none is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove your four line you specified above and just update your routes as this,.

```
$route['admin/news/index/(:num)'] = 'admin/news/index/$1';
```

Comment: please update your quest with all code of your routes.php file

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

You have to include this config parameter in pagination.